# Facebook multi-friend request always highlights first user

Tags: facebook, multi-friend-selector

I am working on an app for iOS. I am using the facebook multi-friend request dialog. I am using it in the touch display mode, and it's being loaded in a UIWebView.

When the dialog loads, the first friend in the list is always highligted, even after I select some friends. This makes it look wrong when selecting users.

Is there a way to change this behavoir, so that no friend cell is highlighted until you tap on the cell?